# Error cannot find symbol with interface in same package

Tags: java, import, package

Hello my network of software wizards.  I have a questions as to why I can not get my class to compile.  I keep getting error: cannot find symbol.  All these classes are within the same package blocklaw. I have tried every variation of import statement but can not seem to remove this error.  The directory structure is blocklaw --> src --> all_classes_here.
I tried changing the package declaration blocklaw.src as well and still no help.
I will share my code here,

```
 package blocklaw;

    import java.security.MessageDigest;
    /*
    * returns a string value of the true fact
    */
    public class TrueFact implements Hashable {
      private String trueFact;
      private String hashFact;
      private String source;
      private String hashSource;
      private int bytesLength;
      private String hashedBytesLength;
      private String hashedHash;

      public TrueFact(String trueFact, String source){
        this.trueFact = trueFact;
        this.source = new Source(source).getSource();
        byte[] bytes = trueFact.getBytes("UTF-8");
        this.bytesLength = bytes.length;
        setHashCode();
      }

      public String getTrueFact(){
         return this.trueFact;
      }

      public String getHashFact(){
        return this.hashFact;
      }

      public String getSource(){
        return this.source;
      }

      public int getbytesLength(){
        return this.bytesLength;
      }

      public String getHashedBytesLength(){
        return this.hashedBytesLength;
      }

      public void setHashCode(){
        this.hashFact = hash(this.trueFact);
        this.hashSource = hash(this.source);
        this.hashedBytesLength = hash(String.valueOf(this.bytesLength));
        this.hashedHash = hash(this.hashFact+this.hashSource+this.hashedBytesLength);
      }

      public String getHashSource(){
        return this.hashSource;
      }

      public String hash(String input){
        try {
           MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

           //Applies sha256 to our input,
           byte[] hash = digest.digest(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));

           StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer(); // This will contain hash as hexidecimal
           for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
              String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & hash[i]);
              if(hex.length() == 1) hexString.append('0');
              hexString.append(hex);
           }
           return hexString.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
     }
```

It is my understanding that all classes within the same package do not need to be import explicitly.   Why then is my error such that it can not find the symbol?

The following is the interface for Hashable...

```
package blocklaw;

public interface Hashable{
    public String hash();
}
```

Comment: Do you know for which class, you are getting this error. is that class is private?

Comment: Its this class. I am trying to compile so I can test this class.  The interface is public with one public class hash().

Comment: Your code should compile, no need to specifically `import` public classes (or protected, or package-private) if they are in the same package of your class. But how exactly are you compiling this code- seems like you use `javac`? Exactly, what command do you use?

Comment: which line in the above code is causing the compilation failure?

Comment: Daniele...good question I am using$: javac TrueFact.java

Comment: Sujay Mohan The error is on 7 and 18.  Cannot find symbol for Hashable or Source - both of which are in same package.

Comment: Could you please post the code for Hashable?

Comment: code for Hashable is very simple: public interface Hashable{public String Hash();}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So As discussed these are the steps to be followed to correct the answer.

```
Compile Source.java
And the String input parameter to the hash function in Hashable.java
Compile Hashable.java
Now go one folder level up.
Add necessary try catch blocks in TrueFact.java
Build blocklaw/TrueFact.java
```

This will compile the TrueFact.java.

Comment: OK i removed the src folder and put all files in under the blocklaw directory, compiled the Hashable interface first and I still get the same error.  That is, cannot find symbol.

Comment: Yes Hashable is in folder blocklaw and I added interface to original post.

Comment: can you post the code for Hashable interface along with package?Also please confirm whether the .class file is present for Hashable in blocksaw package after compiling using javac.

Comment: Yes sir I added it in  --> it's in package blocklaw;  I am using javac TrueFact.java to compile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199853/discussion-between-sujay-mohan-and-philip-caputo).

Comment: Sujay, I would love to but I do not know how?? Forgive me.  Tell me how to "accept" an answer and I will get it done for you.

Comment: Please check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In an interface all the methods are public and abstract by nature. so no need to explicitly mention public keyword in your public String hash(); method
instead you can just say String hash();
Also make sure your hash class is in the same directory and same package.